# Oracle query with LOWER

Tags: sql, oracle

Why this returns 0 rows

```
SELECT GARTUSERID, USER_CODE, UNITID, RANKCODE, RANKID, FIO, LOGINNAME, 
       START_DATE, EXPIR_DATE, NOTE, POSITION, ISCHGPASSWORD, IS_EXPIRDATE,
       IS_BLOCKED, ROW_ID
  FROM ACONTROL.GARTUSERS
 WHERE LOWER(LOGINNAME)=LOWER(:LOGIN) AND ROW_ID=:MD5PSWD
```

and this returns 1 row (as I wanted for the first query)?

```
SELECT GARTUSERID, USER_CODE, UNITID, RANKCODE, RANKID, FIO, LOGINNAME,
       START_DATE, EXPIR_DATE, NOTE, POSITION, ISCHGPASSWORD, IS_EXPIRDATE,
       IS_BLOCKED, ROW_ID 
  FROM ACONTROL.GARTUSERS
 WHERE LOGINNAME=:LOGIN AND ROW_ID=:MD5PSWD
```

Comment: What is the definition for the `LOGINNAME` column, and what does `:LOGIN` contain?

Comment: What is the value of that one LOGINNAME?

Comment: What is your database NLS character setting? Have a look at the NLS_LOWER() function.

Comment: Do a "SELECT LOWER(LOGINNAME), LOWER(:LOGIN)..." and see what they look like.

Comment: LOGINNAME is CHAR(16) and contains 'root' value.  I forgot to mention that this query works from dbartisan but fails in tableadapter's dataset designer

Comment: NLS_LOWER() did not help.  Alex Poole, :LOGIN contains 'root'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be a data type conflict for LOGINNAME? Try using VARCHAR2, as opposed to CHAR since it pads the string with whitespace.

Comment: That's what I've started to think too.  Unfortunetly, I have no control over that field's datatype.  May be I can use TRIM also

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TRIM` keyword to terminate the white space and since it is the type of varchar use `LIKE` instead of `'='` for comparison.